# Поочередно вычесть и перезаписать строки в выборочных столбцах

Tags: python

Всем привет! есть такая табличка, в которой логируются действия по изменению состава корзины.
Описание полей:

- cartcode - id корзины
- p_productcode - артикул добавления(к примеру детская игрушка)
- p_productadditiontype - тип изменения состава корзины ( может быть, добавление ADD, изменение EDIT и удаление REMOVE
- income - оборот в рублях
- goods - кол-во штук
- product - раздел сайта где было совершенно одно из действий по изменению.

Необходимо в разрезе **cartcode** и **p_productcode** с учетом очередности по добавлению(по created_time) провести вычитание по столбцам **income** и **goods**(скомпенсировать добавленные и удаленные значения), да так что если в этих строках при удаление может получится значение меньше нуля, надо записать 0, и продолжить вычитать из следующей строки согласно разрезу по **cartcode** и **p_productcode**.

Исходные данные:

| dy | created_time | p_type | cl_type | cartcode | p_productcode | p_productadditiontype | income | goods | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:40:03 | 300 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1255 | ADD | 500 | 5 | Поиск |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:41:04 | 400 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1633 | ADD | 300 | 2 | Витрина |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:42:05 | 301 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1255 | EDIT | 300 | 3 | Личный кабинет |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:43:06 | 555 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1255 | EDIT | -600 | -6 | Чекаут |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:44:07 | 346 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1633 | REMOVE | -150 | -1 | Чекаут |

То что должно получится :

| dy | created_time | p_type | cl_type | cartcode | p_productcode | p_productadditiontype | income | goods | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:40:03 | 300 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1255 | ADD | 0 | 0 | Поиск |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:41:04 | 400 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1633 | ADD | 150 | 1 | Витрина |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:42:05 | 301 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1255 | EDIT | 200 | 2 | Личный кабинет |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:43:06 | 555 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1255 | EDIT | 0 | 0 | Чекаут |
| 2023-08-16 | 12:44:07 | 346 | Юр.Лицо | 1234 | 1633 | REMOVE | 0 | 0 | Чекаут |

Алгоритм - смотрим связку cartcode и p_productcode соответственно 1234 и 1255 , ищем первый минус по столбцам income и goods опять же в группе cartcode и p_productcode начинаем компенсировать положительные и отрицательные  значения согласно сортировки по дате и времени до 0 если это возможно, в данном случае значения первой строки компенсируются в 0, тк 500-600=-100, эти -100 мы дальше по порядку вычитаем из следующего положительного значения в группе cartcode и p_productcode это 300, 300-100=200, 200 и записывается. А то первое отрицательное значение -600, скомпенсировалось в 0. Если бы отрицательных значений было бы больше , мы бы их вычитали по той же логике(т.е. по порядку до 0 и переходили бы к следующей строке)

Comment: Я лично не понял, как получилась вторая таблица. Лучше распишите логику, как и почему получились такие значения.

Comment: 1ая строка - 4ая строка до 0, остается 500-600=-100 и возвращаемся с этими -100 на 3ю строку , там остается 200, и вторая с 5ой 300-150 остается 150

Comment: понятней не стало. алгоритм надо описать пошагово в самом вопросе. вот прям пошагово.

Comment: Дополнил логикой, постарался описать как это понимаю я

Answer (score 1):

Думаю надо сначала сортировать все по p_productadditiontype
Например сначала суммируется все ADD, потом EDIT потом REMOVE
а после этих действий что то можно сделать
Мой телеграм ник @beniqob
Я хотел забрать этот заказ не понял суть задач